# Changing the Background Color of a Treeview widget in tkinter according to a query result

Tags: tkinter, treeview, python-3.7, background-color

I want to change the background color of a treeview depending on the result of a query, so if the condition of query (condiquery argument) is equal to "" then the background color must be "white" and if the condition is different the colour must be "light blue".

This code works fine but just for the first time ( The colour just changed two times, from white to light blue, and the rest of the times remaing with Light blue color)

Anyone would help me?

```
#Funcion Query Traer Pacientes
    def get_pacientes(self, condiquery):
        #limpio el color de fondo
        self.pac_win.style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, background='white', font=('Lucida Console', 9)) # Formato  del Cuerpo
        global acu_name
        self.acu_name=self.acu_name+1
        print(self.acu_name)
        #Limpio la tabla de pacietnes
        records = self.pac_win.pactree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.pac_win.pactree.delete(element)
        #Consulto los pacientes
        query = 'SELECT * from Padron where Status = 1 ORDER BY Paciente ASC'
        if condiquery !="":
            query = condiquery
            self.pac_win.style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, background='light blue', font=('Lucida Console', 9)) # Formato  del Cuerpo
        dbregpac = self.run_queries(query)
        #lleno la tabla 
        for row in dbregpac:
            self.pac_win.pactree.insert("",0,text = row[0], values = row[1])
```